# Why does CreateWICTextureFromFile require ShowWindow?

Tags: c++, textures, direct3d

I'm writing some D3D11 apps and am using DirectXTK's CreateWICTextureFromFile to load a texture file into SRV. I wanted to show my rendering window only when I start to draw the scene (after initializing models, textures, shaders, constant buffers, etc.) so I've created the window early on but I omit the ShowWindow until later.

Unfortunately I get an error unless I show the window prior to creating the texture:

```
// ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW); // works
hr = DirectX::CreateWICTextureFromFile(device.Get(), L"../../Common/Resources/Textures/green_grid.png", nullptr, psTexture.GetAddressOf());
ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW); // fails
```

HResult error:

```
No such interface supported
```

Also it seems to work fine if I show the window at the end of initialization as long as I don't load any textures with this function.

Maybe I don't have a good understanding of how a window works with respect to the D3D API. Looking at CreateWICTextureFromFile's parameters, I only see a dependency on device and the SRV. I'm not sure why there's a dependency on the window visibility?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you call WICTextureLoader (which uses the [Windows Imaging Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wic/-wic-about-windows-imaging-codec)) you need to initialize COM as noted in the [documentation](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/WICTextureLoader#initialization).

In your main entry-point, add:

```
if (FAILED(CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINIT_MULTITHREADED)))
    // error
```

> The fact that `ShowWindow` happens to initalize COM is an interesting side-effect, but that's definitely **not** a function you are required to call to use my GitHub libraries.